# How to draw a contour with python?

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

In python,if I have a set of data

```
x y z
```

If I want to make a contour

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x, y, z = np.loadtxt('w51e2-I.log', unpack=True)
plt.contour(x,y,z)
plt.show()
```

But it doesn't work.
How can I solve my problem?

Comment: ``x,y,z`` need to be 2D arrays. You might want to use ``numpy.meshgrid`` to create those first. See also the documenation  http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.contour .

Comment: So I have to change the z to np.meshgrid(z)? But it says:TypeError: Length of y must be number of rows in z. Should I change z in to a matrix?

Comment: If your data is not structured, you might want to look into ``plt.tricontour``, see also http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/tricontour_vs_griddata.html .

Comment: I made a plot with the code of "Contour plot in Python importing txt table file"! But that looks a little bit different from what I expected. Can I zoom in the plot to see what happened in details? Sorry for the stupid questions, I'm new to python. Thanks!

Comment: @larry In the window that opens when running the script you should see [a navigation toolbar, which allows zooming](http://matplotlib.org/users/navigation_toolbar.html).